# How to connect to database using PDO in multiple classes?

Tags: php, pdo

I have multiple classes and most of them need to connect to database,

How can I set PDO options/host/dbname etc only once and then use it in every class while having the following in mind:

1. I don't want to wrap PDO
2. I need to close the PDO connection after each query (`$db=null`), so I simply cannot just use `$db = new PDO(...)` and then pass `$db` to my classes

I want to skip having this in every class that needs to connect to the database:

```
<?php

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

Comment: `I need to close the PDO connection after each query` why?

Comment: @kuh-chan Because of performance issues, too many visits per second and too many queries that cannot be cached, as PDO doc mentions: `The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object... To close the connection, you need to destroy the object...`

Comment: how many requests do you expect per second?
anyways... what about a static factory method that creates a new pdo object?

Comment: If your opening a connection each time, well seems like making a class to handle the DB connection should cut that down some.  Then you will re-use one connection, instead of having multiples.  For example you could be connecting 100 times to the DB as your application runs.  It's better to connect 1 time.  There is some re-use of connections though, but it's generally cleaner to connect into one place and then share that same link.

Comment: @kuh-chan At peak times (maybe 20-30 minutes daily) they are expecting to have ~2-5000 queries per second, at other times it is like ~500 qps that's why I'm forced to abandon frameworks and keep it as simple as I can, I'm really stressed about it so trying to search and make sure for every single line of code I do X_X I researched and apparently closing the connection after query in PDO helps...

Comment: @J.Doe - that is way to many.  I would use something like `sphinx searchd` or another in memory data storage option.  It's not trivial.  With `sphinx` we do around `120k` searches a minute and over `150mil` searches a day on a server with `64G` of ram.  What you said is `300k` searches a minute` and sphinx was almost 20x faster then the DB in my testing.

Comment: Maybe your processes is faster then mine, but you can distribute sphinx over multiple servers.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Queries are as simple as `WHERE id=X` (id is int(11) and primary key so indexed) , and also `SELECT`s are on medium tables (largest table that needs `SELECT` has 200,000 rows with like 15 short columns), `INSERT` happens on much larger tables but no search on them!

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Also everything that can be cached is cached on cloudflare or disk, so I'm just having these simple queries to handle (the 5k is the absolute maximum maybe for a few minutes per day), anyways, can you think of any way for my question?

Comment: Yea make a simple class that connects to the DB then pass that aound instead of connecting multiple times, you can use a Singleton or Mutiton to maintain the state but you have to know the good and bads of that.  Here is a pair of traits and interfaces I use for them. https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Pattern

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want complete control over opening and closing connections then I suggest we only centralise the `$dsn`, `$user`, `$pass` and `$options` variables. I'm assuming there are also variables like `$host`, `$db` and `$charset` which you did not reveal to us but lets add them.

Lets call this file `global_db.php`:

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$db = "mydb";
$charset = "UTF-8";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
```

That looks like we have all the goods there, keep in mind I am not testing this so we might get a syntax error or two.

Now in our classes or other php files where we want to open a connection.

Lets call this page `fooClass.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'global_db.php';

class FooClass {
    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO(
                    $GLOBALS['dsn'],
                    $GLOBALS['user'],
                    $GLOBALS['pass'],
                    $GLOBALS['options']);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
        }
    }
}
```

That should do the trick or at least give you a general idea on where to go from here on your own route. There are many other ways to accomplish similar but no need to overcomplicate things.

nJoy!